# How to set a column with varchar data type as unique in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Table `ApprovedLeave`

Column names:

- `EmployeeID (int)`
- `Leave(varchar(MAX))`
- `Approved(bit)`

I want to set `Leave` column unique so that user cannot enter same date twice. I cannot take employee id as primary key because same employee can take leave multiple times

Comment: Mr. doublesharp is correct, but I'm not sure that varchar(max) is the correct data type for what you want to do.  What does it represent - an explanation?  A date range?  If it's a date range, you probably want to break it out into a start and an end date.  However, then you'd have to make sure that the date ranges do not overlap for the same employee, which you can't do with just a unique index.

Comment: You can't create a unique index on `varchar(max)`

Comment: I am inserting dates in column Leave using JDBC in java. Is there any other datatype supported?

Comment: Why are you using a `varchar(max)` column to store a date???

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Oh, that pallid, colourless "Why" of yours! Why isn't it in red, italicised, bold, in red and underscored (in red)?

Answer (score 1):

Create a column for date. SQL Server 2008 has a new `date` datatype instead of using `datetime`. Don't use a `varchar(max)` to represent a date.

```
LeaveDate ( date )
```

Now your primary key must include the new column.

```
alter table ApprovedLeave add constraint PK_ApprovedLeave primary key ( EmployeeID, LeaveDate ); 
/* don't forget to drop it if already exists */
```

This means that you can enter multiple records for the same employee, but not on the same date.

Comment: the datatype 'date' is giving error in the java code which i am using to insert values in the database

Comment: @user1690973 what version of JDBC are you using that it doesn't understand `date`? Maybe you could move to a new version, use `datetime/smalldatetime` instead, or utilize a stored procedure (JDBC really shouldn't care about the data types used in the table, just getting the proper values to SQL Server).

Comment: if you just go for datetime/smalldatetime datatype, be sure to remove time information. You will find a way to do it here in stackoverflow. If you don't remove time information, the PK will always validate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on multiple columns - `EmployeeID` and`Leave`. Just setting the `Leave` column as unique will mean that it will be enforced regardless of the `EmployeeID`, and I am assuming you want to allow different employees to use the same `Leave` date.

```
ALTER TABLE [tablename]
ADD CONSTRAINT [unique_leave] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
(
    [EmployeeID], [Leave]
)
```

Comment: Column 'Leave' in table 'ApprovedLeave' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index. This error is displayed

Comment: Sorry, missed that before. VARCHAR(MAX) is probably the wrong datatype for your purposes - it can be (2^31)-1 bytes large which would blow up your server if it had to check for uniqueness on that much data.

Comment: I am inserting dates in column Leave using JDBC in java. Is there any other datatype supported?

Comment: You could use either DATE or DATETIME: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675168.aspx

Comment: the datatype 'date' or 'datetime' is giving error in the java code which i am using to insert values in the database

Comment: That sounds like a separate issue :)

Comment: :( I have changed the format accordingly in my code but nothing is working

Comment: With the proper data type, I would recommend validating that the unique values are being enforce via a query editor. Once that is working, perhaps post a new question regarding inserting dates with JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said that Leave represents a date range, you could represent your table as

```
EmployeeID  int
LeaveStart  date
LeaveEnd    date
Approved    bit
```

... and make EmployeeID, LeaveStart, and LeaveEnd the components of a composite unique index.

But that only solves a subset of your real problem, which is that you don't want employees to take leave on overlapping time periods. (The exact same start and end dates are a special case of overlap).  Consider these records:

```
Employee ID = 101, LeaveStart = 1/1/2012, LeaveEnd = 2/1/2012 
Employee ID = 101, LeaveStart = 1/1/2012, LeaveEnd = 2/2/2012
```

That would satisfy your unique constraint, but would still be very wrong.

You can address that with a trigger, or with a constraint involving a UDF, or through very careful business logic in your calling program, but an index won't be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Building on doublesharp's answer, you will have to convert the Leave column data type to datetime. Depending on the format of the date values already in that column you will have to [tweak the code a bit to handle the format(s)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx):

```
-- // Add new column using correct data type
alter table [tablename] add Leave_New datetime not null
go
-- // populate it from existing column:
update [tablename] set Leave_New = convert(datetime, [Leave], 1)
go

-- // Add the unique constraint:
ALTER TABLE [tablename]
ADD CONSTRAINT [unique_leave] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
(
    [EmployeeID], [Leave_new]
)


-- // After you verify that the above is successful, you can drop the old column, and rename the new one: 
alter table [tablename] drop column [Leave]
go
exec sp_RENAME '[tablename].Leave_New', 'Leave' , 'COLUMN'
```